# An installer for Qt apps

Tags: qt, installation

I've created a Qt calculator app using Qt Creator 3.6.0 purely in C++ code (I didn't use Designer)

I would like to know how to use Qt to make it installable for publishing. 
I ran the app in both *Release* and *Debug* modes and have both folders of the two.

I also downloaded and installed *Qt Installer Framework Opensource 2.0.1* for my Qt Creator 3.6.0 (the IDE I use for Qt).

And I also have the *.dll* files needed to run the *.exe* file.

I've searched the Web for it. But since I'm a novice in Qt I can't do the works properly, or I don't understand. (They seem complicated)
Now, is there any straight forward method to use an installer for the app to make as platform independent as possible?

If so, what installer? And how to do the process? This is the first time for me.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/

Comment: OK, thanks. It says *Configuring Qt for Windows
We recommend that you use the following options when you configure Qt For Windows*:

Comment: **configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -release -static -static-runtime -target xp -accessibility -no-opengl -no-icu -no-sql-sqlite -no-qml-debug -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtenginio -skip qtlocation -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtserialport -skip qtquick1 -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtscript -skip qtsensors -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtxmlpatterns -skip qt3d**. It seems a command line statement. My Command Line is on **C:\ Users\ME>**. Should I copy that statement on that path and press Enter key?

Comment: But what is your problem exactly. You were asking about Qt Installer Framework and now you are talking about configuring Qt, like if you would want to build Qt from sources.

Comment: I just followed the link you gave me. It's [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-getting-started.html)

Comment: **You can skip this if you have downloaded a pre-built version of the framework** If you are novice, then just download pre-built binaries and you don't need to do this.